# How to rotate Perspective Camera in 3D Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I'm creating  3d game with libgdx but I have problem,  I want to rotate the camera on touch the screen , so I added this from libgdx wiki

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    float deltaX = -Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * degreesPerPixel;
    float deltaY = -Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * degreesPerPixel;

    camera.rotate(Vector3.Y,deltaX*0.9f);
    camera.rotate(Vector3.X,360-deltaY*0.9f);
    camera.update();


    return true;
}
```

It work but , the problem happens when I touch the screen to rotate and look behind me , the camera rotate like this

[image]

[image]

The land and the world must rotate not the camera,  I used open glad Es before,  and there we rotate the world

```
Gl.Glrotatef(0.0.0)
```

But in libgdx I can't make it rotate normally .

what is the problem in my code ?

```
    @Override
        public void create () {

            camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
            camera.position.set(0f, 5f, 0f);
            camera.lookAt(0f,0f,0f);
            camera.near =0.1f;
            camera.far = 300f;
            modelInstance=new Array<ModelInstance>();
            texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("gtass4.jpg"),false);

            modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
            modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.begin();

            modelBuilder.node().id="Block";
            modelBuilder.part("Block",GL30.GL_TRIANGLES,VertexAttributes.Usage.Position|VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates,
                              new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture)))
                .box(1000,5,1000);

            box=modelBuilder.end();

            modelInstance.add(block=new ModelInstance(box,"Block"));



            texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
            texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

            Matrix3 mat = new Matrix3();

            mat.scl(new Vector2(80.0f, 80.0f));
            box.meshes.get(0).transformUV(mat);


            environment = new Environment();
            environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
            environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

            camController = new CameraInputController(camera);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        }

        Vector3 position = new Vector3();
        private void movement() {
            block.transform.getTranslation(position);
            position.x = x;
            position.z = z;
            position.y = y;
            block.transform.setTranslation(position);

        }


        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .0f, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            movement();
            k=Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond();
            modelBatch.begin(camera);
            modelBatch.render(modelInstance,environment);

            modelBatch.end();
            camera.update();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

            if(keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT)
                camera.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f), 1f);
            if(keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT)
                camera.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f),new Vector3(0f,1f,0f), -1f);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {



            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }


   @Override
    public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        float deltaX = -Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * degreesPerPixel;
        float deltaY = -Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * degreesPerPixel;

        camera.rotate(Vector3.Y,deltaX*0.9f);
        camera.rotate(Vector3.X,360-deltaY*0.9f);
        camera.update();


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. I guess you want to use Euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll) instead of multiplying rotations. Note that you can also modify the view, projection and combined matrices directly, which is somewhat comparable to calling `Glrotatef`, if that is what you want to accomplish. If you don't want to rotate the camera, but instead your modelinstance, then you could just do that of course.

Comment: @Xoppa I want to create a first person camera,  like minecraf and the other games,  but I don't know how to do this,  I searched but without finding any thing,  as I want to move then look right or left .

Comment: In that case you can just use the built-in `FirstPersonCameraController` class. If needed you can modify it as you like.

Comment: @Xoppa I didn't find any toturial about how to use it,  and the toturial  of your site doesn't contain any thing about this,  can you give me example?

Comment: The usage is the same as `CameraInputController`, just replace the classname. Here's an example if you prefer: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/a4805d6a017b80622d6bfdd3a791352257a3c539/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/TextureArrayTest.java

Comment: Please don't use the [java-3d] tag as you don't use the Java3D API.